# Using the Earth Movers Distance in Combination with Complete Linkage Clustering

Tags: multivariate-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am posting to request help understanding a part of a paper [1] on clustering analysis.  I should mention that I am new to clustering analysis

In [1] the authors use the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD) to cluster a set of approximately 50,000 signatures.

They do this in combination with a Complete Linkage Clustering (CLC) algorithm.  In subsection 5.3, at the top of page 642 they state: "in our experiments, we used complete linkage hierarchical clustering [14] given Earth Mover Distances".

**I understand the EMD algorithm and I understand the CLC algorithm, but I cannot see how they are combining the two**.

One way that I thought to do this would be to run the CLC algorithm, and compute the EMD from the original distribution to each level of the  hierarchy, to see which level is the closest.  This does not seem to be what they are doing.  Earlier in Subsection 5.3 on page 641, the authors write  "We can then use EMD to compute distances from cluster centers to the entire data set, allowing for both out-lier detection and cluster assignment.".

So somehow, they seem to be using the EMD in the CLC algorithm for clustering assignment. How could they be doing this, since the EMD is for calculating the difference between *two distributions*, not *clusters within the same distribution*.

I would be grateful for any help anyone could offer.

**Reference**

[1] Applegate, David, et al. "Unsupervised clustering of multidimensional distributions using earth mover distance." Proceedings of the 17th ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining. ACM, 2011.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not read the paper you cite, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering):

"In complete-linkage clustering, the link between two clusters contains all element pairs, and the distance between clusters equals the distance between those two elements (one in each cluster) that are farthest away from each other."

So in CLC the distance between two clusters is equal to some inter-element distance, and in your case inter-element distances are computed via EMD. As far as I can tell, this would be the straightforward application of EMD for CLC.

However I am not sure that that this implies any particular notion of "cluster center". For a given inter-element distance metric, the cluster center will typically by optimizing some function of the element-to-"center" distances, but this could vary (e.g. a "mean" would minimize the sum of distances to all elements, but a "midpoint" would minimize the maximum distance). Independent of how it is defined, a cluster center will be of the same form as a cluster element. So here each cluster center would be a multidimensional distribution.

From the quote you give, it seems like the paper may be doing a two-stage clustering. In stage 1, clusters are computed via CLC (using EMD for inter-element distances). Then they compute "cluster centers" for each of these clusters (how this is done is indeterminate from the information you provide). In stage 2, these centers are then used to re-cluster the data, where data points are assigned to the cluster whose center they are closest to (where "close" is again measured by EMD).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and clear reply.  One thing I am still missing, however, is how they are using EMD to compute *inter-element* distances.  I understand that CLC uses an inter-element distance to calculate distance between clusters, but how could the EMD be used as this inter-element distance?  To my understanding, I thought the EMD calculates the distance between two *distributions*, not the distance between *two points within a given distribution*.  Again, grateful for any clarity you could provide.

Comment: I did not read the paper, but typically a multi-dimensional distribution would be called a "point" in some high-dimensional space. Typically EMD would applied to discretized distributions, e.g. a pair of points in $R^n$, where each point is a distribution, and $n$ is the number of histogram bins.